# Video Player in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, mp4

I am developing an application in Flex in which I need to play an MP4 file. The video is playing properly but not fitting in the video player window; some back area is left above and below the video clip. I tried to adjust the size but all in vain.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you using the Flex "VideoPlayer" component?
If so, try changing the "scaleMode" property for your video player, by default it has the value of "letterbox", which is why you're seeing those black areas above and underneath the video. (Possible values are "none", "stretch", "letterbox", or "zoom".)